# Change value of field if input is not in choices Django ImportExportModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have this model field as an example:

```
compliance_approve_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None, choices=review_status_choices)
```

with these choices:

```
for_review = 'FOR REVIEW'
approved = 'APPROVED'
rejected = 'REJECTED'
review_status_choices = [(for_review, 'FOR REVIEW'), (approved, 'APPROVED'), (rejected, 'REJECTED')]
```

A simplified version of fields with choices.

I want to be able to make a default value in which if a user imports from a file and puts something other than a 'FOR REVIEW', 'APPROVED' or 'REJECTED', or is `NULL`, it would default to `None`. I thought adding a `default=None` would do it, but it accepts other values in Django's `ImportExportModelAdmin`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a [widget](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html) subclass and use it on the field. Put the logic you need in the `clean` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```py
class ComplianceStatusWidget(widgets.CharWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if value:
            for status, text in models.YourModel.review_status_choices:
                if value.strip().lower() == text.lower():
                    return text
        return None
```

Some improvements to this:

1. Consider using a [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets) in your HTML to avoid duplication.
2. Consider passing the choices into the widget using constructor for better separation of logic.  This would help you to reuse the widget in other contexts.
3. The code above is case-insensitive which might not be what you want.

Comment: I understand how this works now. Thanks!!!

Comment: is there a way I can pass a parameter to that class? Something like `class ComplianceChoicesWidget(CharWidget, choices):`.

Comment: Yes, there is an example [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/8ac147d5d2775cd23026b153fd978a1492088251/import_export/widgets.py#L168) - if it's still not clear feel free to post another question.

Comment: Hello Matthew, I posted another question. I hope you'd be able to answer it as well. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69732004/12415287)