# How to display cleaned email data in django import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have this widget:

```
class EmailWidget(CharWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if value:
            email_field = EmailField()

            if email_field.clean(value):
                return value
        return None
```

which I use here:

```
some_email= fields.Field(attribute='some_email', 
        widget=EmailWidget(), 
        column_name='some_email')
```

cleaning is fine but it does not specify the data to be cleaned on the table view in errors.

[image]

what I was expecting was something like this:

[image]

I only need to specify it and display it among the list of errors in the second row and second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not implementing the widget correctly.  From the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.Widget.clean) on `clean()`:

> Returns an appropriate Python object for an imported value.
>
> For example, if you import a value from a spreadsheet, clean() handles conversion of this value into the corresponding Python object.
>
> Numbers or dates can be cleaned to their respective data types and don’t have to be imported as Strings.

This means that `clean()` doesn't need to perform any additional validation.  In the case of an email field, it would only need to return a string object, and `CharWidget` will do that for you.

However there is a simpler way to achieve what you want.  If your model field is declared as [EmailField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#emailfield), then you just need to set the [`clean_model_instances`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html?highlight=clean_model_resources#import_export.resources.ResourceOptions.clean_model_instances) Meta attribute on your resource, and the email will be validated automatically during import.

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    author_email = models.EmailField('Author email', max_length=75, blank=True)


class BookResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        clean_model_instances = True
```

When tested with the example application, the output is:

[image: email validation failure]

Comment: yeah, clean_model_instances is what I'm looking for all this time. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, the `clean_model_instances = True` did not catch the foreign key and the decimal fields as part of what should be cleaned or be caught. I posted it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69758971/12415287).