# Catch decimal.ConversionSyntax django import export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I need to be able to display the error regarding invalid decimals and invalid foreign keys into a much more user-friendly way.

I thought the `clean_model_instances = True` would catch it but it did not.

Invalid decimal error:

[image]

Invalid foreign key error:

[image]

What I wanted to display was the error along with all other errors here:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can solve this.

1. For `DecimalWidget` declare it as `CharWidget` - this will handle any input string and if you have `clean_model_instances` enabled, then the error will be raised when the model object is validated.
2. For `ForeignKeyWidget`, you will have to override the `clean()` method so that it raises a `ValueError` for a non-existent reference.  IMO this isn't ideal because it is breaking the contract for the `clean()` function.  The error message isn't perfect, but it does achieve what you want.

```py
class ValidatingForeignKeyWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            val = super().clean(value)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValueError(f"{self.model.__name__} with value={value} does not exist")
        return val


class BookResource(ModelResource):
    price = fields.Field(attribute='price', widget=widgets.CharWidget())
    author = fields.Field(attribute="author", widget=ValidatingForeignKeyWidget(Author))

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        clean_model_instances = True
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Tho, how bad would it be to override the `clean()` method? Would it affect the import-export library in any way?

Comment: No I cannot see that it would cause any problems, and I cannot see another way of achieving it.  The issue is more theoretical, that we are overriding clean to perform validation, but because it is handling the error more gracefully I think this is ok.